# Time for bootstrapping a node in alphanet

Tags: alphanet, bootstrapping

I have started a tezos node on my local machine in alphanet and it seems to take  two hours to move head 12 days after downloading more than 800MB of data. The node seems to be actively getting data from peers.
What is the total data size that will be downloaded till it bootstraps?
How long does the bootstrapping normally take?
Is there anyway to speed it up?

Comment: After performing the steps and running the node - it gives the following error : Mar 8 02:16:53 - node.main: Starting the Tezos node...
Mar 8 02:16:53 - node.main: No local peer discovery.
Mar 8 02:16:53 - node.main: Peer's global id: idrULwbkWGa1K5vo66c8zio1iiNCYb
Mar 8 02:16:53 - node.worker: bootstrapping chain...
tezos-node: Error: Missing key in store: chain/8eceda2f/genesis/hash Are we missing anything here? Thanks.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/276)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/276)

Answer (score 2):

Alphanet size is currently around 13 GB. It is a very IO intensive process and it is recommended you use SSD where it it should take less than 4 hours to complete.

There isn't a commonly used quicksync for alphanet, but mainnet quicksync files can be found here https://www.tzdutch.com/quicksync/

Comment: Thanks. my sync took around 10 hours and was done finally.